# Compare two columns in excel and seeing if values are the same

Tags: excel, vba

This image shows the before. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8BmxxuBoGYnVkhDaEF2b1J6ejA

The objective of the code is to look at the value of the first cell of column 1 then look for that same value in Column 4 by going down the Column. In the case of the first cell in Column 1 it would be honey and the corresponding row in Column 4 is 6. Then it will duplicate the values from Column 5 and Column 6 that corresponds with honey in Column 4 and put it in Column 2 and Column 3 in the row that corresponds with honey for Column 1. Every time a cell in Column 2 or Column 3 is filled it will be colored blue. I don't know how to get the syntax right to set a string in one cell equal to a string in another cell and determining if the cell is blank in the first place.

This image shows the after.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8BmxxuBoGYnX1VXWllaQTAxWFE

```
Sub checkcolumns()
'j determines the row for Column 1. n determines the row for Column 4'
Dim j As Integer
Dim n As Integer
j = 1
n = 1

 'The first part is a Do While loop and is intended to check if the first 
 'cell is filled with something. If it's not then the code won't run.'

Do While Cells(j,1).Value <> Not vbNullString

 'The next part determines whether the first cell from Column 1 and 
 'first cell from Column 4 are the same. If they aren't then it will 
 'search for the cell in Column 4 that has the same value. n denotes the row 
 'for column 4 and the Do Until loop will determine which row in column 4 
 'has the exact value as the cell we're looking at from Column 1

     if Cell(j,1) NotEqual Cell(n, 4)
         Do Until cell(j, 1) Equalto Cell(n, 4)
             n = n + 1
         End

  'The next if statements first determine whether Column 2 of the row we're 
  'looking at has a value already. If it does not then that cell is 
  'populated with whatever value is in Column 5 of the corresponding row for  
  'Column 4 which is found with n. This is repeated for Column 3 using 
  'Column 6.

        if Cells(j, 2).Value <> vbNullString Then
            Cells(j, 2) = Cells(n, 5)
            Cells(j, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        End if
        if Cells(j, 3).Value <> vbNullString Then
            Cells(j, 3) = Cells(n, 6)
            Cells(j, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        End if
   'This else statement below is for the case where the cell value from 
   'Column 1 on that row is equal to the cell value of Column 4 on that
   'same row, so j and n would be equal.
    Else
        if Cells(j, 2).Value <> vbNullString Else
            Cells(j, 2) = Cells(n, 5)
            Cells(j, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        End If
        if Cells(j, 3).Value <> vbNullString Else
            Cells(j, 3) = Cells(n, 6)
            Cells(j, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        End If
    End If
    'Once it has checked the first row in Column 1. It will then look at the 
    'second row.
    j = j + 1
End

End Sub
```

Comment: Use VLOOKUP????

Comment: And conditional formatting for the color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this formula in B2:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$F$7,2,FALSE)
```

And then put this formula in C2:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$F$7,3,FALSE)
```

A2 is the value you want to search in column D
$D$2:$F$7 creates a static table to search
2 or 3 is the column in that table (from first col of table) you want returned
False requires an exact match on the search

Once you put them in the cells, drag them down.